# It is possible that a database get damaged?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

It is possible that when I export a database from phpmyadmin the database get damaged?

The actual issue is that if it is possible, that was the reason why I couldn't login to my website like admin.
Because than I imported an earlier database and now I can log in.

So do you offer me that sometimes I should export my database, like a backup?

This is a real danger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a database can get damaged. Yes you should do backups (exports). No, phpMyAdmin does not damage a database when exporting it.